# Django: Redirect to web application on launch

Tags: python, django

Whenever I "runserver" on my Django application, it always takes me to "http://127.0.0.1:8000/" which throws an error since my application is on "http://127.0.0.1:8000/polls." Is there any way that I can run the server at the latter url instead of the former one?

Comment: I'm sure there's a better way, but you could always setup a simple django redirect at that location

Answer (score 1):

You can add a route your `urlpatterns` to redirect automatically

```
urlpatterns = [
    ....

    # automatically redirect '/' to '/polls'
    url(r'^$', RedirectView.as_view(url='/polls')),
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to edit your project's `urlpatterns`.

Exemple, my project is **mysite**.

I need to edit the `urlpatterns` in *mysite/url.py*

I guess you should have something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'polls/', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ...
]
```

Replace it with something like this:

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', include('polls.urls')),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    # ...
]
```